# keylogging using ubuntu 1

Tags: shortcut-keys

My 13 year old son has Latitude 2100 netbook driven by Ubuntu 1.
We are concerned he is being bullied online, therefore I have downloaded the keylogging patch from the website to monitor his activity

However I can find no information as to if this is the case or how I access his activity. Where or how do I find this information ?

Comment: Doesn't exist and there didn't exist ever ubuntu or ubunto 1.

Comment: Which keylogging patch? Which website?

Comment: Are you sure that keyloggers are legal in your country?

Comment: Your son will probably be very angry when he discoveres you are spying on him. Really, just talk with your son about it.

Comment: my son is going through hell and we just need to help him, probably not legal but its the only way we can get to the bottom of it

Comment: Wouldn't it be in your sons best interest finding a solution together with your family, people from school (school principal, teachers, counselor), etc.? Your son needs to learn that bulling and the like is fought with moral courage, having people getting together and standing against this, not by in turn again violating the rights of others. If bullying really is the case, he doesn't deserve the additional punishment of losing all his privacy. When were you planning to uninstall the keylogger? Surveillance technology is convenient once it's deployed, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

Before to follow this answer, you may reflect a little at the fact that can be *illegal* to monitor someones keystrokes (of course without permission).

Assuming you're talking about one of [these Ubuntu releases](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) and not about [Ubuntu One](https://one.ubuntu.com/) that is a cloud service, go in [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal) an run next command:

```
sudo apt-get install logkeys
```

This will install Logkeys Keylogger on Ubuntu.

Before to start keylogging process first time, create a log file in your home directory or wherever you want:

```
touch keylogging.log
```

Use Logkeys to start keylogging process:

```
sudo logkeys --start --output keylogging.log
```

Now your keylogger is running in background and you can close the terminal. The output will be stored in the keylogging.log.

To stop keylogging, kill logkeys process:

```
sudo logkeys  --kill
```

To read keystrokes recoreded by keylogger, use:

```
strings keylogging.log
```

[Read official documentation](http://code.google.com/p/logkeys/wiki/Documentation) for more options.